# CSS classes not applying to AJAX content with JQuery 3.0

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am adding `<tr>` and `<td>` tags to a table dynamically. The `<table>` itself is static, along with its attributes. The issue i'm having is that the `table table-bordered table-striped table-hover` classes are NOT applying properly to the table rows. However, If I simply cut the classes from my DOM inspector and paste them back in verbatim, the styles take effect.

I have narrowed the problem down to upgrading to JQuery 3.x.x (specifically 3.1.1 is what I'm using). My code base has been running on JQuery 2.2.4 and I only see these issues after attempting to upgrade.

Here is the table with no changes made to the DOM inspector: [image]

Here is the table after only cutting the CSS classes out, and pasting them directly back in:

[image]

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="" id="multipleResultsTable">
 <tr>
    <th style="" class="checkBoxForMerge">
        Select
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The SimilarAccounts field is required." id="SimilarAccounts" name="SimilarAccounts" type="hidden" value="True">
    </th>
    <th>Account Name</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
</tr>
    <tr class="searchable">
        <td style="" class="checkBoxForMerge" data-guid="">
            <input class="insured-selector" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="generic_Selected" name="generic.Selected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="generic.Selected" type="hidden" value="false">
        </td>
        <td data-guid="">
            <a class="multipleResults" data-action-url="" data-guid="">Result 1</a>
        </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Harley Quinn</strong></li>
                </ol>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="searchable">
        <td style="" class="checkBoxForMerge" data-guid="">
            <input class="insured-selector" id="generic_Selected" name="generic.Selected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="generic.Selected" type="hidden" value="false">
        </td>
        <td data-guid="">
            <a class="multipleResults" data-action-url="" data-guid="">Result 2</a>
        </td>
            <td>
                <ol>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Floyd Lawton</strong></li>
                </ol>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Relevant JQuery:**

I tried manually removing the classes and adding them back in via JQuery (see commented code below), but it was not successful either.

```
var multipleResultsTable = $("#multipleResultsTable");
var mergeTool = $("#mergeTool");
var searchString = $("#searchString");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: { searchString: searchString },

    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Url !== undefined)
            window.location.href = data.Url;
        else {
            multipleResultsTable.html(data);
            multipleResultsTable.show();
            if ($('#SimilarAccounts').val() === "True") {
                mergeTool.show();
                $('.checkBoxForMerge').show();
            }
            //multipleResultsTable.removeClass('table table-bordered table-striped table-hover');
            //multipleResultsTable.addClass('table table-bordered table-striped table-hover');
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        bootbox.alert("Error showing search results");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up kind of doing what Frozenex suggested. For my original problem, I was replacing all of the guts inside of `<table>` with a list of `<tr>`s that were passed back as an MVC partial view.

For the fix, I just added a `<table>` element to the partial instead of having it consist of only `<tr>`s. Then, Instead of replacing the guts of `<table>` I placed a wrapper `<div>` around the whole table (outside of the partial) and instead replaced its contents with the fixed partial.

Very easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same issue... Only temp solution to fix the problem was to update the entire table in success callback.